# How to use continuationKey in an async function using node.js & Azure storage table

Tags: node.js, azure-table-storage

I am trying to implement the continuation tokens in an async function with Azure table storage,

Below is my code,

```
async function acceleration_threshold1_exceed(carId){
  PartitionKey = carId + "_" + "acceleration_threshold1_exceed";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   query = new azure.TableQuery()
  .select(['*'])
  .where('PartitionKey eq?', PartitionKey);
   tableSvc.queryEntities('eventsdata',query,null, function (error, result){
          if(!error){
            if(result.entries.length != 0){
              resolve(result.entries.length);
            }else{
              reject(NaN);
            }    
          }else{
              reject(error);
          }
        });
      });
    }


module.exports = {
  acceleration_threshold1_exceed
}
```

Comment: What SDK (node package) are you using?

Comment: {
  Fleetium: '1.0.0',
  npm: '6.14.8',
  ares: '1.16.1',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  cldr: '37.0',
  icu: '67.1',
  llhttp: '2.1.3',
  modules: '83',
  napi: '7',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  node: '14.15.1',
  openssl: '1.1.1g',
  tz: '2020a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.40.0',
  v8: '8.4.371.19-node.17',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}

Comment: Nope that's not it. Are you using `azure-storage` node package? If so, then what version?

Comment: @gary Could you please tell me which package you use?

Comment: "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use package `azure-storage` to query Azure table storage entity, please refer to the following code

```
async function queryEntitiesSegmented(table, tableQuery, continuationToken){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        tableSvc.queryEntities(table, tableQuery, continuationToken, (error, results)=> {
            if (error) {  reject(error); } 
            else { resolve(results);  }
        });
    });
}

async function queryAllEntities(table){
    var tableQuery = new azure.TableQuery();
    
    var continuationToken = null;
    var entities = [];
    do{
        var results =  await queryEntitiesSegmented(table, tableQuery, continuationToken);
        continuationToken = results.continuationToken;
        entities.push.apply(entities, results.entries);
    }
    while(continuationToken!=null);
    return entities;
}
```